# Swift global Variables Not Updating

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've have been searching for this answer for days. Whenever i try to instantiate a new viewcontroller called "Govind" I get a SIGARBT error. The reason why I get a SIGARBT error is because in the view controller called I use the variables; yourVariable, ASIN, VariationImages, to find specific nodes in my database. The values for yourVariable, ASIN, and VariationImages do not change, when I set them equal to the values from firebase. The values from firebase are not nil.   Here's my code

```
 import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseDatabase
    var yourVariable = ""
    var ProductsNumber = 100
    var ASIN = ""
    var Weblink = ""
    var VariationImages = 5

    class Initial: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, 
    UICollectionViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var FrontPageCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var UIFrame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var DatabaseHandle = nil as DatabaseHandle!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference()

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.DatabaseHandle = ref.child("Frontpage").child(String(indexPath.row)).observe(.value, with: { (TheCategory) in
            yourVariable = TheCategory.childSnapshot(forPath: "Category").value as! String
            ASIN = TheCategory.childSnapshot(forPath: "ASIN").value as! String
        self.DatabaseHandle = self.ref.child(TheCategory.childSnapshot(forPath: "Category").value as! String).child(TheCategory.childSnapshot(forPath: "ASIN").value as! String).child("VariationImages").observe(.value, with: { (NumberOfVariationImages) in
            VariationImages = Int(NumberOfVariationImages.childrenCount)
            })
        })
        CallGovind()
    }

    func CallGovind() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Govind")
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FrontpageCell", for: indexPath) as! myCell
        self.DatabaseHandle = ref.child("Frontpage").child(String(indexPath.row)).child("Thumbnail").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            cell.FrontpageImages.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: snapshot.value as! String), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Menu"), options: [.continueInBackground, .progressiveDownload])
        })
        cell.FrontpageImages.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        cell.FrontpageImages.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.FrontpageImages.clipsToBounds = true
        return cell
    }

    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    }

//Here's where the data goes into the second view controller

    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseDatabase


    class Testing: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var DatabaseHandle = nil as DatabaseHandle!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Populate view
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cells", for: indexPath) as! myCell
        self.DatabaseHandle = ref.child(yourVariable).child(ASIN).child("VariationImages").child(String(indexPath.row)).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
           cell.myImageViews.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: snapshot.value as! String), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Menu"), options: [.continueInBackground, .progressiveDownload])


          })
        return cell
}
```

Everywhere where the DataBaseHandle is, produces an error because it is an empty string because the variables have not updated

Comment: Please show the code where the crash occurs.

Comment: I edited the post and added the code that you requested for, thank you for replying @Paulw11

Comment: Can you post the code for Govind? Since this is what is crashing, you should post it.

Comment: The second code post with the class "Testing" is "Govind". Govind is simply the identifier I gave to the view controller. @ryantxr

Comment: are you sure you will get value in collectionview didSelect method put breakPoint and chek TheCategory.childSnapshot(forPath: "Category").value as! String

Comment: 100% sure, I checked and printed to the terminal to see if a value came back and there was. However, the problem is that the global variables whether they are in a struct or not, they do not seem to update. If you know a better way to transfer variables between classes, I will try. I cannot use transfer variables with the seque because I am simply instantiating a new view controller, and I've tried to transfer variables through the delegate and they do not work. Any suggestions???? @JaydeepVyas

Comment: I have posted another solution to use singleTon more preferable

Comment: Firebase dataHandler is called at last did you tried using Breakpoints you are calling Govind at end of your handler but if you will use breakpoint you will notice Govind is executed first then after that datahandler

Comment: @GovindGharmalkar Will you please edit the question formatting first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your invocation of function `CallGovind()` is getting executed before the completion handlers are done. This means your other view controller is called **before** the variables are set.

```
... .observe(.value, with: { (TheCategory) in
    // Code in here will get executed asynchronously
    // and likely will get called later
    // Since you set variables in here, and they
    // are not set by the time you call the other 
    // view controller.
}

CallGovind()  // gets called BEFORE above code
```

One possible solution is to make sure that the other view controller is called after the completion blocks are done.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.DatabaseHandle = ref.child("Frontpage").child(String(indexPath.row)).observe(.value, with: { (TheCategory) in
        yourVariable = TheCategory.childSnapshot(forPath: "Category").value as! String
        ASIN = TheCategory.childSnapshot(forPath: "ASIN").value as! String
        self.DatabaseHandle = self.ref.child(TheCategory.childSnapshot(forPath: "Category").value as! String).child(TheCategory.childSnapshot(forPath: "ASIN").value as! String).child("VariationImages").observe(.value, with: { (NumberOfVariationImages) in
            VariationImages = Int(NumberOfVariationImages.childrenCount)
            // Call other controller here so that the variables
            // are set
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                CallGovind()
            }
        })
    })

}
```

Comment: THANK YOU @ryantxr the code worked out perfectly. THANK YOU I HAD THIS PROBLEM FOR DAYS. THANK you so MUCH!!!

Comment: I recommend you look into alternate ways to pass data between controllers.  You can take a look at [legendary-potato](https://github.com/ryantxr/legendary-potato).

Comment: Thank you so much @ryantxr, I really appreciate from the bottom on my heart all the help, its my first time using Stackoverflow, and you show a great sense of community. Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

AS ryantxr stated callGovind inside the closure and also good way to share variable among all the classes is singleTon.

As per my knowledge you have to create SingleTon class to manage this type variable like create seperate singleton file

```
import Foundation
/**
 * Created by Jaydeep on 13-Feb-17.
 */

public class Singleton
{
    var yourVariable : String = ""
    static let shared = Singleton()
    private init()
    {
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Singleton.shared.yourVariable = "xyz"
```

You can access singleTon class object anywhere and always you get last updated value.

Comment: Thank you, I never looked into a SingleTon class, but since I have, it seems that it would work out. Thanks for your help! @JaydeepVyas

Comment: this variable is not updated into an "open class" why ?